# adding items from a list to another list using python

Tags: python, list

Suppose I have a list A contains [[2,3],[4,5]] and there is another list B with [7,8], I want to add the items in B to A, the results should be: [[7,1,2][8,4,5]]. I tried to use two loops,but I got the wrong results.

```
import numpy as np

news = []

for x in A:
    for y in B:
        news.append(np.insert(x,0,y))
print news
```

Comment: what ... how do you get `7,1,2` ?

Comment: My goal is to add the first item "7" in B to A[0], and "8" to A[1]

Comment: wouldnt it be `7,2,3` ?

Answer (score 2):

Use `numpy.column_stack`.

```
In [6]: import numpy as np

In [7]: a = np.array([[2,3],[4,5]])

In [8]: b = np.array([7,8])

In [9]: np.column_stack((b,a))
Out[9]: 
array([[7, 2, 3],
       [8, 4, 5]])
```

Comment: It's worth noting that the ordering on column_stack is important as it denotes the order of append.

Comment: Thank you, Akavall. Does it avoid adding items iteratively to another list? Or just concatenating both of them?

Comment: @Mike I believe that under the hood `numpy.concatenate`, creates new arrays, and populates them with values from `a` and `b`. They are in different memory locations, so any changes you make to `a` or `b` afterwards would not affect your new array.

Comment: @Akavall, thank you. I should take a look at numpy manual carefully.

Answer (score 0):

You could use a list comprehension that doesn't return anything. Instead it just modifies list `a`. The `zip` method iterates over the items in `a` and `b` simultaneously.

```
In [78]: [x.insert(0,y) for x,y in zip(a,b)]
Out[78]: [None, None]
```

We see new values for `a`, while `b` is unchanged.

```
In [79]: a
Out[79]: [[7, 2, 3], [8, 4, 5]]

In [80]: b
Out[80]: [7, 8]
```